# Program to send UDP messages at a constant rate of a few Kbit/s sending them at 3Mbit/s?

Tags: c, networking

The following program is supposed to send a message of size `bytes` in a
constant rate of `args.rate` bit/s on any channel (assuming the channel supports that rate) via UDP. There's probably a better way to do it but I believe this should work:

```
double interval = (double)(bytes * 8) / (double)args.rate;
struct timespec s, e;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &s) == -1)
  REPORT_AND_EXIT;
while(true) {
  ssize_t rc = sendto(sockfd, args.msg, bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)(&peer),
      (socklen_t)sizeof(peer));
  if (rc == -1)
    REPORT_AND_EXIT;
  do {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &e);
  } while (ELAPSED(s, e) < interval);
  s = e;
}
```

For completion sake [here](https://a.cocaine.ninja/bkidqj.tar.xz) is the entire code (both receiver and transmitter).

With `bytes = 6`, `args.rate = 638000`, running it on lo, both iftop and nload (two network monitoring applications) show a constant rate of about 3Mbit/s, while I was expecting 638Kbit/s. I could not find what was wrong with my program so I used tcpdump to see what was going on, and unless I'm misinterpreting its results it informs me that after one second exactly 13286 6 byte UDP packets had been sent, amounting to 637728 bits or 637.728 Kbit/s, which is what I was expecting. So why is iftop showing me 3Mbit/s? I set both iftop and tcpdump to monitor lo only and I had nothing else running (tcpdump captured a single ICMP request that did not come from my application, but it should be negligible).

[Here](https://a.cocaine.ninja/rbpwho) is the output of `tcpdump -ttt -i lo` and below is a R script that calculates from the log how many bits have been sent after one second (after `cut -d' ' -f1 log | cut -d'.' -f2 | sed 's/^/0./ >log2`)

```
library(dplyr)                                                                  
df <- read.csv("log2", header=F)                                                
names(df) <- c("time")                                                          
df %>%                                                                    
  mutate(cum=cumsum(time), ct=as.numeric(row(df)), bytes=6*ct, bits=8*bytes, kbits=bits/1000) %>%
  filter(cum >= 1.0 - 1e-4) %>%                                                  
  head
```

Results:

```
   time      cum    ct bytes   bits   kbits                                 
7.5e-05 0.999931 13285 79710 637680 637.680                                 
7.5e-05 1.000006 13286 79716 637728 637.728                                 
7.6e-05 1.000082 13287 79722 637776 637.776                                 
7.5e-05 1.000157 13288 79728 637824 637.824                                 
7.5e-05 1.000232 13289 79734 637872 637.872                                 
7.5e-05 1.000307 13290 79740 637920 637.920
```

Comment: You should sleep for the next required interval, not smoke the CPU in a hard time-checking loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitoring applications show you the real network traffic, which includes the UDP overhead.

The IP header is 20 bytes, and the UDP header is 8 bytes, totaling to a 28 bytes overhead. The 6 bytes packet you send are 34 bytes in real size.

With those 13,286 packets are 451,724 bytes, or 3,613,792 bits long. This is close to the 3Mbits you see.

The overhead below IP are not counted in IP monitoring because not relevant for an IP connection, and because it is not constant on a network path (for example, it can change when going through a modem).

Comment: "_The IP header is 12 bytes..._" An IPv4 header is, at least, 20 bytes, exclusive of any IPv4 options or the payload. A six-byte UDP datagram would result in a minimum packet size of 34 bytes. That does not include any overhead for the layer-2 protocol, which for ethernet would be a minimum of 18 bytes.